# My Machine is taking more than usual to boot (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot

I've been working with Ubuntu as my main OS for the past two/three months, and up until two or three weeks ago it began to boot slower than usual,
reading in some forum posts I began to run diagnostics to see what is taking so long and these are my findings:

Using `systemd-analyze blame` I found this:

```
     34.900s dev-sda5.device
     25.922s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
     20.245s systemd-sysctl.service
     14.145s keyboard-setup.service
     12.364s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      8.995s systemd-journald.service
      8.710s fwupd.service
      8.329s systemd-modules-load.service
      6.025s dev-mqueue.mount
      6.025s sys-kernel-debug.mount
      6.024s dev-hugepages.mount
      4.851s ModemManager.service
      4.822s accounts-daemon.service
      4.000s NetworkManager.service
      3.960s snapd.service
      3.266s lightdm.service
      2.635s kmod-static-nodes.service
      2.262s polkitd.service
      1.947s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-326a4872\x2d5f7a\x2d4995\x2dbf
      1.752s ufw.service
      1.274s apparmor.service
      1.144s teamviewerd.service
      1.132s udisks2.service
```

And then using `systemd-analyze plot  > /tmp/analyze.svg`, these were the results:

[image: these were the results]

And here is the full resolution image:

[image: full resolution image]

On both of these two, the `dev-sda5`(my root partition, this is an HDD) is the one taking most of the time using 34.9s.

[image: my root partition]

Is there anything I can do to speed my boot time up to the old ones? It was at least half if not a third of the actual one.

If any of you think that any other times are longer than usual, please let me know, I'm quite new to Linux in general.

Thanks.

Comment: Systemd is an additional feature which was introduced from Ubuntu 16.04 and runs checks on disks for errors. Thats why it takes time. I don't know how to disable this but rolling back to previous versions may do the job